# Add/Edit row in table using react and redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I’m new to react&redux and trying to build app using react-redux and I need help. When I click on add new person the form shows up, when I fill the form and click save button the values from the form (name, job title, phone, birthday) should be added to the table, and operations are always the same for everything(the value of operations row is "default" two buttons edit and delete ). I try to create reducer that will get the values from the form and add it to the table but I didn't achieve that. I don’t know how to define reducer so that happened when I click save button. Can someone help me how to solve this? Thank you. Here is the link of the project. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-hill-0xiht

Comment: Did you read the react-redux docs and understand the concepts?

Comment: You can make debugging easier when you use the redux dev tools, you can add it to your store like this: `const store = createStore(reducer,undefined,window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());`

Comment: @SuleymanSah Hello Sir, yes I am. Why?

Comment: @Boco91 please check/console step wise flow, one more thing there is no actions there.

Comment: you should create a function in MainForm to handle user input in your form. Then, pass it as props to your EditForm.

Comment: Hello, I manage to solve some problems, now I get all values from form in table when I enter them, just don't know how to save them to the table (how to update table) when I click save. Here is the link of project, can someone look and help me solve this. https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-austin-050ow